# Python pandas Compare values of the last two rows and perform action

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have a pandas series as shown

I want to compare the value of the last two rows "Total" and "SMA20" to perform an action. (Please note the Pandas dataframe is large, Im pasting only last row)

```
myData = {'Date':[2022-01-17 15:27:00+05:30], 'total': [200],
      '20SMA': [220]
      }
```

I tried to store them in two separate variables by doing below

```
last_sma = myData['SMA20'].iloc[-1:]
last_total = myData['Total'].iloc[-1:]
```

Then try comparing both of the them,

```
if last_sma > last_total:
print('SMA is large')
```

I get the below error.

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

When I try see the variable content its shown as below

Date
2022-01-17 15:27:00+05:30    215.155
Name: SMA20, dtype: float64

Its pandas series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on Stackoverflow!

What you are getting with the way you make your slices are pandas `Series`

```py
last_sma = myData['SMA20'].iloc[-1:]  # last_sma is a single value Series
last_total = myData['Total'].iloc[-1:]  # last_total is a single value Series
```

`myData['SMA20']` returns a `Series` which holds the data from column `SMA20`, and the `.iloc[-1:]` returns a slice of this `Series`, with only one record, but a `Series` nonetheless.

Comparing 2 series with `>` operator returns another `Series`, holding the true of false value for comparison for each pair of records. In your, case it holds a Series with a single true or false value.

As stated by the error message you get, trying to collapse a `Series` of boolean values into a single boolean value is not well defined - even if your `Series` holds a single record.

If you only need to compare the last value, a simple way to make your code work is to remove the `:` in your slices.

```py
last_sma = myData['SMA20'].iloc[-1]  # returns the single value at location -1
last_total = myData['Total'].iloc[-1] # returns the single value at location -1

if last_sma > last_total:
print('SMA is large')  # should work now!
```